# Regular Expression for string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like

e.g  AHDFFH XXXX

where 'AHDFFH' can be char string of any length.
AND   'XXXX' will be repeated no. of 'X' chars of any length which needs to be replaced by auto incremented database value in a table.

I need to find repeated 'X' chars from above string using regular expression.

Can anyone please help me to figure this out..??

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-regular-expression-tutorials/ this might help you

Comment: I would recommend you post some actual patterns you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
\b(\p{L})\1+\b
```

**Explanation:**

```
<!--
\b(\p{L})\1+\b

Options: case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\p{L})»
   A character with the Unicode property “letter” (any kind of letter from any language) «\p{L}»
Match the same text as most recently matched by capturing group number 1 «\1+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

is your meaning some chars + (on or some)space + some numbers?

if so u can use this regexpression:

```
\w+\s+(\d+)
```

c# codes like this:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\w+\s+(\d+)");
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m = regex.Match("aaaa 3333");
if(m.Success) {
    MessageBox.Show(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```